# Set parameters of Gnuplot from array in bash script

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I'm trying to load parameters of Gnuplot from configuration file using bash script and plotting data. The point of this problem is access to these parameters. This is my attempt of solution, but some errors occured.

```
gnuplot << EOF
values="${params[*]}"
do for [val in values] {
val=sprinf("%s", j)
set $val
}
```

I got this output:

```
gnuplot> do for [j in values] {
                              ^
         line 0: invalid complex constant
         line 0: undefined variable: j
gnuplot> set 
             ^
         line 0: Unrecognized option.  See 'help set'.
gnuplot> }
         ^
         line 0: invalid character }
```

I'm sure, I have multiple strings inside of params array.
Thanks

Comment: UPDATE:
I've tried "set val" too.

Comment: Is there any reason for doing it this way and not having a configuration file and loading it with `load 'config.gp'`?

Comment: Yes, it's my task, I've got structure of configuration file (for Gnuplot and other stuff) and I'm creating a script to handle this file.
Actually, it's not my code, I found it here at [stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52453/gnuplot-shell-variable-substitution-and-arrays)
but it made sence for me, so I used it.

Answer (score 0):

Your gnuplot version is too old. The iteration structure `do for` is supported only since version 4.6.

Then, the following works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
params[0]='grid'
params[1]='xrange[0:10]'

gnuplot -persist << EOF
values="${params[*]}"
do for [val in values] {
    eval('set '.val)
}
plot x
EOF
```

But that works only, if the array entries don't contain any white spaces. Usually, you would create a configuration file with the content

```
set grid
set xrange [0:10]
```

and load this with `load 'config.gp'`.