# Unknown syntax in Gnuplot?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I am learning pass BASH list to Gnuplot without generate an intermediate file. The answer I found was very useful (by Christoph at [Set parameters of Gnuplot from array in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503745/set-parameters-of-gnuplot-from-array-in-bash-script)). And the code is below.

I am confused about two symbols. One is **"** in *values="${params[*]}*. The other is **.** in *eval('set '.val)*. I did not find the syntax in the manual. Could you tell me what they are for?

```
### Code
#!/bin/bash
params[0]='grid'
params[1]='xrange[0:10]'

gnuplot -persist << EOF
values="${params[*]}
do for [val in values] {
    eval('set '.val)
}
plot x
EOF
####
```

Comment: You'll find a full list of operators, like the `.`, in the gnuplot manual in the Chapter `Expressions -> Operators`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There here document is constructed from shell variables. `${params[*]}` is bash code for "all elements in the array `params` concatenated into a string". It's not all gnuplot code.

Replace `gnuplot -persist` with `cat` to see what `gnuplot` sees:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                  
params[0]='grid'                                                             
params[1]='xrange[0:10]'                                                     

cat << EOF                                                                   
values="${params[*]}                                                         
do for [val in values] {                                                     
    eval('set '.val)                                                         
}                                                                            
plot x                                                                       
EOF
```

resulting in:

```
values="grid xrange[0:10]
do for [val in values] {
    eval('set '.val)
}
plot x
```

`values="grid xrange[0:10]` is a variable assignment:

```
gnuplot> values="grid xrange[0:10]
gnuplot> print values
grid xrange[0:10]
```

`.` is string concatenation:

```
gnuplot> print "foo" . "bar"
foobar
```

So the result is that `set grid` and `set xrange[0:10]` are evaluated by gnuplot as if you had typed them in manually.

Comment: I know the meaning of ${params[*]}. But I don't understand the function of symbol " before it.

Comment: It starts a string literal in gnuplot. gnuplot allows but does not require a second `"` to close it

Comment: Thanks, guys! I got it. String literal without closing double quote is really not a good syntax.